# How do I get a Broadcom BCM4312 working on a Dell XPS M1330?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.  When I plug in the ethernet cable the internet works fine, but I can't see any wireless network in the networking manager.  The wifi switch is definitely on on my laptop!  It's a Dell XPS M1330.  [Edited: the network card is Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g ]

`nm-tool` gives me this:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:23:AE:28:FE:A2

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.26
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254
```

Comment: Can you add the kind of wireless card it is to your question?

Comment: How do I find out what kind of wireless card it is?  That's part of my question!

Comment: Thank you!  0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Comment: Duplicate question / best answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395?newreg=8ebab9959d134399a324eec8c795ec45

Answer (score 2):

Okay, once I found out the wireless card name I was able to find the answer.  I needed to do `sudo apt-get update` and after that the drivers appeared under "additional drivers". 
Thanks!